# Deleting empty space in Ubuntu vdi

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, virtualbox, downloads, vdi

I downloaded a file (I didn't save it, I used archive manager and that failed) in my Ubuntu VirtualBox vdi, 66GB, and I can't seem to find the actual file. When I am in Ubuntu the free space shows that there is no file, but outside the vdi file, my Mac OS X believes that file is still taking up 66GB. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Downloaded == saved. try /tmp, it should be there until reboot. ...also, we don't support my Mac OS X here, if Ubuntu says it's not there, then it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did restart Ubuntu so I guess it is gone. I'll look into the Mac OS X issue--thanks again!